# Remove columns from data set in R having constant non-missing values

Tags: r, constants, missing-data

Consider the following data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(a=c("Yes","Yes",NA),b=c(2,4,3),c=c(NA,3,3),d=c("B","B","B"))

     a b  c d
1  Yes 2 NA B
2  Yes 4  3 B
3 <NA> 3  3 B
```

Desired output:

```
  b
1 2
2 4
3 3
```

Comment: Do you need to *identify* which columns meet this condition? Removing them is trivial.

Comment: [Please show us what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i tried:data[sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x))>1)]
but col a and col c were not removed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove constant columns with or without NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253732/remove-constant-columns-with-or-without-nas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data[sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))) > 1]

#   b
# 1 2
# 2 4
# 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sapply with is.na() and any():

```
> data[sapply(data, function(data) !any(is.na(data)))] 
  b
1 2
2 4
3 3
```

Comment: I do not want to remove columns have missing data...my primary aim is to remove columns with same values,if some column has some missing and the rest of the values are same i want to remove those too.Consider data <- data.frame(a=c("Yes","Yes",NA),b=c(2,4,3),c=c(NA,3,3),d=c("A","A","A")...my output should be only column b