# Remove constant columns with or without NAs

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get many `lm` models work in a function and I need to automatically drop constant columns from my data.table. Thus, I want to keep only columns with two or more unique values, excluding `NA` from the count.

I tried several methods found on SO, but I am still not able to drop columns that have two values: a constant and NAs.

My reproducible code:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,NA,5), y=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA),z=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
d=c(2,2,2,2,2))

> df
    x  y  z d
1:  1  1 NA 2
2:  2  1 NA 2
3:  3 NA NA 2
4: NA NA NA 2
5:  5 NA NA 2
```

My intention is to drop columns y, z, and d since they are constant, including y that only have one unique value when `NA`s are omitted.

I tried this:

```
same <- sapply(df, function(.col){ all(is.na(.col))  || all(.col[1L] == .col)})
df1 <- df[ , !same, with = FALSE]


> df1
    x  y
1:  1  1
2:  2  1
3:  3 NA
4: NA NA
5:  5 NA
```

As seen, 'y' is still there ...
Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have a `data.table`, you may use `uniqueN` and its `na.rm` argument:

```
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(v) if(uniqueN(v, na.rm = TRUE) > 1) v)]
#     x
# 1:  1
# 2:  2
# 3:  3
# 4: NA
# 5:  5
```

---

A `base` alternative could be `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1, df)`

Comment: It work perfectly, thank you. I like this solution because it also works with character cols (other solution based on variance, do not) and is full data.table. Thanks!  By the way, what is the difference between unique and uniqueN ...?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Regarding your question, I think you need to be more specific, otherwise I will probably just regurgitate the help text ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is simple solution with function `Filter` in base `r`. It will help.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,NA,5), y=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA),z=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                 d=c(2,2,2,2,2))
# Select only columns for which SD is not 0
> Filter(function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) != 0, df)
    x
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4: NA
5:  5
```

**Note:** Don't forget to use `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but needs some explanation. `Filter` iterates across a list (including, in this case, a data frame), returning those elements that return `TRUE` (or something coercible thereto) when passed to the supplied function. In this case, `sd` (like `var` in some of the other answers) will be 0 for the undesired columns (which `Filter` coerces to `FALSE`) and the desired columns will be a non-zero number (which `Filter` coerces to `TRUE`).

Comment: @alistaire You have explained very correctly. May be it will be good to modify the call to explicitly return `TRUE` (just for better understanding).

Answer (score 2):

Check if the variance is zero:

```
df[, sapply(df, var, na.rm = TRUE) != 0, with = FALSE]
#     x
# 1:  1
# 2:  2
# 3:  3
# 4: NA
# 5:  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
df[,which(df[,
       unlist(
        sapply(.SD,function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) >1))]),
   with=FALSE]

    x
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4: NA
5:  5
```

For each column of the *data.table* we count the number of unique values different of NA. We keep only column that have more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean DROPing those columns, here is a solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,NA,5), 
                 y=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA),
                 z=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                 d=c(2,2,2,2,2))

for (col in names(copy(dt))){
    v = var(dt[[col]], na.rm = TRUE)
    if (v == 0 | is.na(v)) dt[, (col) := NULL]
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my solution?

Comment: @zx8754  The difference is obvious. In your method, you copy the original data table and then construct a new one. Mine is  updating the original `data.table`  by reference, a more `data.table` way. By the way, when I was working on my solution, I did not see yours.

Comment: The question is not "how to drop columns" but "how to apply a rule to drop columns", I used var and you used var. From the question you can see OP is already doing subset to a new variable: `df1 <- df[ , !same, with = FALSE]`

Comment: @zx8754  Again, I want to let you know when I was working on my solution, you did not post yours. I do think two answers both using `var` function is a problem. There is third answer using `sd` function, which is essentially `var` function. Two answers use some kind of `unique` function, do you think they are also problematic?.  I really do not understand why you pay such attention to the `var` function? It is a very common function many people can think of. Except this function, my solution is fundamentally different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

`all(is.na(.col)) || all(.col[1L] == .col)`

to

`all(is.na(.col) | .col[1L] == .col)`

Final code:

```
same <- sapply( df, function(.col){ all( is.na(.col) | .col[1L] == .col ) } )
df1 <- df[,!same, with=F]
```

Result:

```
    x
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4: NA
5:  5
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing `constant` columns,

1. Numeric Columns:-

   ```
   constant_col = [const for const in df.columns if df[const].std() == 0]
   print (len(constant_col))
   print (constant_col)
   ```
2. Categorical Columns:-

   ```
   constant_col = [const for const in df.columns if len(df[const].unique()) == 1]
   print (len(constant_col))
   print (constant_col)
   ```

Then you drop the columns using the drop method

Answer (score 0):

```
library(janitor)
df %>%
  remove_constant(na.rm = TRUE)

    x
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4: NA
5:  5
```